# IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible

Tags: python, pandas

```
 def multiple_dfs(sheet, row=2):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("testing.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

    f1 = {
        'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
        'income': [40000, 50000, 42000],
    }

    f2 = {
        'amount': ['Chest', 'Bras', 'Braa'], 
        'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]
    }

    frames = [f1, f2]


    for f in frames:
        try:
            wb = load_workbook("testing.xlsx")
            ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("aaa")

            writer.wb = wb
            writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)

            row = ws.max_row + 2
        except:
            pass 

        df = pd.DataFrame(f)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)
        writer.save()
    # writer.close()

multiple_dfs('aaa')
```

I got this error, but I can't fix it. I adapt this short representation of what is happening in my code, but it is hard to see where is the real problem. Here is the

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_and_update_xlsx_sheets.py", line 144, in <module>
    create_and_update_worksheets()
  File "create_and_update_xlsx_sheets.py", line 140, in create_and_update_worksheets
    writer.save()
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 824, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  ...
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.py", line 61, in get_active_sheet
    raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```

How could I fix that issue?

**P.S.** Be aware that error is displayed half the time.

Comment: load_workbook and ExcelWriter/to_excel are two different way to deal with Excel files, I don't think you can do them together. It's unclear what is broken here, partially due to the the try: except: block (which catches all exceptions... this shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: I don't understand that error, what is two seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like what you want to do is just write each DataFrame to the same sheet (appending it below the last), so I think you can write this as:

```
start_row = 1
for df in frames:  # assuming they're already DataFrames
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=start_row, index=False)
    start_row += len(df) + 1  # add a row for the column header?
writer.save()  # we only need to save to disk at the very end!
```

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, if you don't need to load a workbook, you can merely use xlsxwriter instead of openpyxl; it hasn't this problem. You can also create a workbook with the regular

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
#...
wb= Workbook()
ws=wb.active
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_filepath, engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    writer.book=wb
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
    #useful code
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet, ...)
    writer.save()
```

now you can work with both pandas.to_excel and the interesting methods of openpyxl that are not translated into it (that's not my hack; found it here but can't find where)

Answer (score 4):

Same error, `IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible`, consistently reproduced when a writer is created, then saved, without having written anything. Example:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')
writer.save()
```

Stepping through the code, the workbook doesn't contain any sheets at time of writing, visible or otherwise, despite having sheets before calling `save`.

Granted, hard to match that to your code, but a clue to you or next dev coming across same error.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do `wb.save("filename.xlsx")` rather than use excelwriter at all.

`writer.save` is an excelwriter method while openpyxl has its own save method that takes a filename after you opened a workbook.

You can also use the `wb.sheetnames` and `wb.create_sheet` to navigate sheets.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = load_workbook(PATH + "yourfile.xlsx")
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter(PATH + "yourfile.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

wb2 = []

if "MySheetName" in wb.sheetnames:
     wb2 = wb["MySheetName"]
else:
     wb2 = wb.create_sheet("MySheetName",-1)  #Auto add at the end

#wb2 is now the active sheet for wb

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
     wb2.append(r)

wb.save(PATH + "yourfile.xlsx")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Creating the sheet beforehand did the trick for me (error message disappeared) : `writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name)` with `openpyxl` engine

Comment: The create_sheet also did it for me

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas 1.3.5 I needed to assign the engine as xlsxwriter.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('path-to-.xlsx-file',engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:     
    df.to_excel(writer, 'spreadsheet-name')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

The error message also acts as a catch-all error. With this in mind, check to see that there are no issues with any of the dataframes you are trying to write into a sheet. I noticed my dataframe itself returned an error. Once I debugged my dataframe, my excel file was able to be written.

Answer (score 0):

If creating a new Excel file does not work with the above error message, it seems that we are trying to create a corrupt file without sheets.

Then, our Plan B is to append to a valid, empty, Excel file. Empty, but with one sheet. That one sheet has no data, so for our purpose, this file is *empty* .

The easiest way to create such empty file is use the Windows File Explorer, and use the context menu on the right mouse button to select New, Microsoft Excel Worksheet.

Then, change your python code to `append` to this empty file:

```
pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, mode = 'a') as writer:
```

If you want to do this all in python, you'd save this empty file once, and use python code to copy it to your "new" empty Excel file(s).

Answer (score -1):

working perfectly fine on pandas **1.1.5** and openpyxl **3.0.5.**

Change your pandas and openpyxl library on above mentioned version.

Comment: downgrading is not a solution.