# IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible reading from a CSV file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
first-name,last-name,email-address
Yes,Beth,bethfat@gmail.com
Iran,Dajango,django@me.com
Paul,Walker,info@walker.com
Ray,Johnson,JJRay@gmail.com
```

I'm trying to convert this CSV file into a Excel file for further use by using Pandas. How I'm doing so is by reading the data from a webpage:

```
import requests

def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        "Connection": "close",
        "User-Agent": "TBG/Converter (TBG;file-converter)"
    }
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return req.content


def parse_html(html):
    retval = {}
    data = html.split("</head>")
    data = data[-1]
    data = data.split("\n")
    retval["header"] = data[0].strip()
    data = data[1:-1]
    emails = set()
    for email in data:
        emails.add(email.split("<br>")[-1])
    retval["userInformation"] = list(emails)
    return retval
```

And writing it to a temporary CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

def write_to_xlsx(data_dict, filename):
    tmp_filename = "/tmp/{}.csv".format(rand())
    with open(tmp_filename, "a+") as tmp:
        data = [data_dict["header"]]
        for item in data_dict["userInformation"]:
            item = item.split(",")
            item = ",".join([c.strip() for c in item])
            data.append(item)
        csv_format = "\n".join(data)
        tmp.write(csv_format)
    print tmp_filename
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename) as ew:
        pd.read_csv(tmp_filename).to_excel(
            ew, index=False, sheet_name=tmp_filename.split(".")[0], encoding="utf-8"
        )
        ew.save()
```

During the writing of the Excel file I get an error telling me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 70, in <module>
    write_to_xlsx(sorted_data, config["filename"].format(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]))
  File "converter.py", line 63, in write_to_xlsx
    ew.save()
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 985, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 989, in close
    return self.save()
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1018, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 367, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 284, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 266, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 95, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, write_workbook(self.workbook))
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.py", line 94, in write_workbook
    active = get_active_sheet(wb)
  File "/Users/admin/bin/python/printers/venv/mailchimper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.py", line 61, in get_active_sheet
    raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```

What is causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: ok why are you converting the csv into spreadsheet, when Pandas can read csv

Comment: @skrubber I have to create a xlsx file to import into another system.

Comment: have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840960/indexerror-at-least-one-sheet-must-be-visible. defining an active worksheet and writing to it should help.

Comment: Can you include the URL? Please [edit] the question to add enough code to allow us to run the script and recreate your error message.

Comment: The error message also acts as a catch-all error. With this in mind, check to see that there are no issues with any of the dataframes you are trying to write into a sheet. I noticed my dataframe itself returned an error. Once I debugged my dataframe, my excel file was able to be written.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
Like the error said, the engine created a new excel file without any sheet in it, so some time it looks corrupted.
I debugged all my code and commented almost everything to try to understand this issue. It occurred sometimes when the "writer" try to find the sheet. Sometimes it just flow as normal while creating the file and converting the data frame to the sheet it self.
So, to avoid this behavior, found a solution in the Stack Overflow.

The link of the solution: [IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840960/indexerror-at-least-one-sheet-must-be-visible)

Worked fine. The only thing that was bothering me was the creation of a blank sheet to assure that the file don't get corrupted. So, what I did was, if the file has this "Sheet" and also has more then one sheet, remove it.

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('the_file.xlsx')
sheets = wb.sheetnames
name = 'Sheet'
if name in sheets and len(sheets)>1:
    wb.remove(wb[name])
    wb.save('the_file.xlsx')
```

For the propose of what need, was good but I will look more if I can do this kind of remove in the creation, or when saving the file, to avoid load it again. A more elegant solution.

If I find (or anyone), we can post in here. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of TheBasalt has a rational explanation, but the solution in his link did not work for me.

If creating a new Excel file does not work with the above error message, it seems that we are trying to create a corrupt file without sheets.

Then, **our Plan B is to append to a valid, empty, Excel file**. Empty, but with one sheet. That one sheet has no data, so for our purpose, this file is *empty* .

The easiest way to create such empty file is use the Windows File Explorer, and use the context menu on the right mouse button to select New, Microsoft Excel Worksheet.

Then, change your python code to `append` to this empty file:

```
pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, mode = 'a') as writer:
```

If you want to do this all in python, you'd save this empty file once, and use python code to copy it to your "new" empty Excel file(s).